# Selecting table from drop down list using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey guys just wondering how i go about using a drop down list to show different php tables? The divs are currently set to hidden but when i do select a table from drop down list and press submit i want it to come up ( div is called fixtures )... please help

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


  if($_POST['chooseoptions'] =='form2') {
  // show fixtures table
  }
  elseif($_POST['chooseoptions'] == 'form3') {
  // change current round number
  }
 elseif($_POST['chooseoptions'] == 'form4') {
 // update user tips
 }
 elseif($_POST['chooseoptions'] == 'form5') {
// reset
} 
 } ?>

<html>
<body>

<form name="work" id="work"  action="POSTBACK" >

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

<p>Select Table:
<select name="chooseoptions" id="chooseoptions" >
<option value="blank"> </option>
    <option value="form2">Form 2 : Display tip table</option>
<option value="form3">Form 3 : Change rounds</option>
<option value="form4">Form 4 : Update table/option>
<option value="form5">Form 5 : RESET</option>
</select></p>

<div id="fixtures" name="fixtures" style='display: none'>
</div
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See example below: Evaluate with PHP and print based on the result.

Adding the class will probably help. On clientside you can control the div with using css. In the example you can use the classes 
for enabled once:

```
.fix-enable{}
```

and for the disabled one

```
.fix-disable{
    //for example disabled
    display:none;
}


    <html>
    <body>

    <form name="work" id="work"  action="POSTBACK" >

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

        <p>Select Table:
        <select name="chooseoptions" id="chooseoptions" >
            <option value="blank"> </option>
            <option value="form2">Form 2 : Display tip table</option>
            <option value="form3">Form 3 : Change rounds</option>
            <option value="form4">Form 4 : Update table/option>
            <option value="form5">Form 5 : RESET</option>
        </select>
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php 
    $classname = "fix-disable";
    if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $classname = "fix-enable";
    }?>
    <div id="fixtures" name="fixtures" class=<?=$classname?>>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @K Mich not really what is the set supposed to do ? isnt there any where of making it hide/show div in php when submit is pressed?

Comment: You can of course enable the style conditionally. So in case not submitted add style, otherwise leave it away.

Comment: @K Mich i get you but i dont know the code for the styling thats where the problem is

Comment: See my changed example. Maybe it will help to add css classes which you can control with CSS. If it doesn't help can you explain a bit more what you want exactly.